# Existe alguma forma de salvar o valor do input em uma session?

Tags: php, html

Eu preciso salvar o valor digitado pelo usuário em um `input` sem usar `form`.
Pensei em `SESSION`, porém não conheço nenhuma forma de fazer isso.
Existe?

O input: `<input type="text" name="valor">`

Quero salvar em `$_SESSION['valor']`

Comment: Não tinha visto o "sem usar form". Talvez a melhor solução seja com javascript.

Comment: E como salvo em SESSION com javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar fazer uma requisição via ajax pra um código PHP, acredito que a melhor solução seja o js como o Diego comentou, assim via POST vai ser possível armazenar algo na variavel $_SESSION['valor'] em um script PHP.

Segue abaixo um exemplo com jQuery:

```
$("input[name=valor]").keypress(function(){
    $.post( "salvaSession.php", { dado: $("input[name=valor]").val() } );
});
```

Ou seja, toda vez que for pressionado uma tecla no campo, irá enviar uma request POST para salvaSession.php, onde salvaSession.php conteria algo como:

```
<?php
session_start(); //se ainda não começou a session.
$_SESSION['valor'] = $_POST['dado'];
?>
```

Esse é o conceito básico, agora basta aprimorar pra que não haja tantas requests, talvez no lostFocus do campo.

Comment: Detalhe importante: não se esquecer de **sanitizar** os dados antes de salvar na sessão (i.e. verificar se o formato dos dados está ok e o cliente não enviou uma requisição maliciosa). Caso contrário, você pode ficar vulnerável a um ataque de *injection*, dependendo de como você usa esses dados salvos (ou mesmo a um XSS, se você ecoar os dados de volta pro usuário).